# Cannot do the set off process of prepayment with spesific bill using web services in Acumatica

Tags: web-services, acumatica

I have a problem in set off processing of Prepayment document with spesific Bill document. It happen only for 1 vendor, because there are a lot of prepayment documents from this vendor (it's about more than 6000 records).

this below is my code.

```
sCon.getLoginSettlementVoucher(context);
                        AP301000Content billSchema2 = context.AP301000GetSchema();
                        List<Command> cmds = new List<Command>();
                        billSchema2.DocumentSummary.Type.Commit = false;
                        billSchema2.DocumentSummary.Type.LinkedCommand = null;

                        var command2 = new Command[]
                        {
                            new Value { Value = docTypeSV, 
                                        LinkedCommand = billSchema2.DocumentSummary.Type},
                            new Value { Value = refNbrSV, 
                                        LinkedCommand = billSchema2.DocumentSummary.ReferenceNbr},
                            billSchema2.Applications.DocTypeDisplayDocType,
                            billSchema2.Applications.ReferenceNbrDisplayRefNbr,
                            billSchema2.Applications.Balance,
                            billSchema2.Applications.AmountPaid
                        };

                        try
                        {
                            var applications = context.AP301000Export(command2, null, 0, false, true);
                            int rowApp = applications.Count(); int ind = 0;
                            foreach (var data in applications)
                            {
                                string docTypeApp = data[0].ToString();
                                string refNbrApp = data[1].ToString();
                                string balanceApp = data[2].ToString();
                                decimal balApp = Convert.ToDecimal(balanceApp);
                                string amountPaid = data[3].ToString();
                                string index = ind.ToString();

                                if (refNbrApp == AcuRefNbr)
                                {
                                    billSchema2.DocumentSummary.Type.Commit = false;
                                    billSchema2.DocumentSummary.Type.LinkedCommand = null;
                                    billSchema2.Applications.ReferenceNbrDisplayRefNbr.LinkedCommand = null;

                                    cmds.Add(new Value { LinkedCommand = billSchema2.DocumentSummary.Type, Value = "Bill" });
                                    cmds.Add(new Value { LinkedCommand = billSchema2.DocumentSummary.ReferenceNbr, Value = refNbrSV });
                                    cmds.Add(new Value { LinkedCommand = billSchema2.DocumentSummary.Vendor, Value = vVendCode });
                                    cmds.Add(new Key
                                    {
                                        ObjectName = billSchema2.Applications.DocTypeDisplayDocType.ObjectName,
                                        FieldName = billSchema2.Applications.DocTypeDisplayDocType.FieldName,
                                        Value = docTypeApp
                                    });
                                    cmds.Add(new Key
                                    {
                                        ObjectName = billSchema2.Applications.ReferenceNbrDisplayRefNbr.ObjectName,
                                        FieldName = billSchema2.Applications.ReferenceNbrDisplayRefNbr.FieldName,
                                        Value = refNbrApp
                                    });

                                    cmds.Add(new Value { LinkedCommand = billSchema2.Applications.ServiceCommands.RowNumber, Value = index });

                                    if (docAmtSV == balApp)
                                        cmds.Add(new Value { LinkedCommand = billSchema2.Applications.AmountPaid, Value = docAmountSV });


                                    else if (docAmtSV < balApp)
                                        cmds.Add(new Value { LinkedCommand = billSchema2.Applications.AmountPaid, Value = docAmountSV });
                                    else if (docAmtSV > balApp)
                                        cmds.Add(new Value { LinkedCommand = billSchema2.Applications.AmountPaid, Value = balanceApp });

                                    cmds.Add(billSchema2.Actions.Save);
                                    var result2 = context.AP301000Submit(cmds.ToArray());

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
```

And then I got an exception message like this below in Submit process.

```
 Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=utf-8', but expected 'text/xml'.

 The request failed with the error message:

--

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <title>Request timed out.</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <style>

     body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 

     p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}

     b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}

     H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }

     H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }

     pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}

     .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}

     .version {color: gray;}

     .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}

     .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }

     @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {

      pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }

     }

     @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {

      pre { width: 280px; }

     }

    </style>

</head>



<body bgcolor="white">



        <span><H1>Server Error in '/AcuInterface' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>



        <h2> <i>Request timed out.</i> </h2></span>



        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">



        <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.



        <br><br>



        <b> Exception Details: </b>System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out.<br><br>



        <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>



        <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">

           <tr>

              <td>

                  <code>



  An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>



              </td>

           </tr>

        </table>



        <br>



        <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>



        <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">

           <tr>

              <td>

                  <code><pre>



[HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out.]

</pre></code>



              </td>

           </tr>

        </table>



        <br>



        <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>



        <b>Version Information:</b> Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1098.0



        </font>



</body>
```

```
--.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fix this problem, I just have to increase timeout of HttpExecution in web.config file inside of Acumatica ERP instance folder. 
..............

..............

by Default Acumatica will set this timeout = 300. It's mean 300 seconds or 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Since the error you are getting is indicating a time out, and that you are only getting it for the one vendor that has around or more than 6000 prepayment documents, you might want to augment the time out value before making your call.
This question here deals with augmenting the time out value for a Screen Based API call : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43273901/how-to-set-the-timeout-while-exporting-data-using-webservices-api-in-acumatica).

To resume what is being said there, please use the following line to set the timer to a bigger value.

context.Timeout = 700000;

Comment: I already tried your answer, I set context.Timeout = 1000000; but it still show the same error..